# Editing title block/frame in Eagle

Tags: cad

As you may know, along with my previous posts in SE I've shown myself as getting familiar with Eagle. And hence, new things to learn are coming and some are not always transparent.

A simple thing such as making a proper title block/frame in Eagle is not an easy task to me now. I've tried Google but the available answers out there are not satisfying

I can make a title block now which is done similarly to adding a component

However, it's more meaningful to customize the information on the block such as some description, project name, author.... are not editable

the project's name is currently tied to the project file name and cannot be changed. Other fields are customized by using Text command but the fonts, size are not consistent with the ones come with the frame.

I'm confused already

Thanks in advance for help!

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately EAGLE doesn't have too many options when it comes to frames and titles.

Actually, title blocks and frames are considered by EAGLE as symbols. You can find them in the `frames.lbr` library.

So go to `File` - `Open` - `Library` and select `frames.lbr`. Go to `Library` menu then `Symbol` and select the frame you want to modify.

Now delete the text variables, so that those fields would be empty. When adding the frame in a schematic you can use the `Text` command to add any text you like.

Save the library or create a new, customized one.

It is not a solution, it's just a workaround to the problem.

[image]

For a list of `Special Text Variables` look at the end of this [page](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/93.htm).

Answer (score 4):

To set the value of the variables in the title block:

- Right click the title block (at it's origin, where the cross is).
- Click Attributes
- Click New
- Enter the name you want to change "DRAWING_NAME" for example
- Enter the value you want displayed "Awesome Schematic Name" for example
- If you want custom attributes, edit the symbol and add your own special fields by using a greater-than symbol like ">PROJECT_NAME"

Answer (score 3):

I use the smash command on the frame, then I delete the info in the fields I don't want and put whatever in there..

- Select the smash tool after you have chosen and placed your frame
- click on the bottom left corner of the frame (you'll see the x if you zoom in) to free up the title block text
- then change it, select your size and layer and presto.