# Cadsoft Eagle Version Control

Tags: eaglecad

For solidwork/photoshops and many other softwares, they come with a "history" or revision log. You could always easily go back to the previous step of components or check how it changed.

Is there such thing for Eagle? There are tutorials out there, but it could only [visualise the change](https://www.element14.com/community/thread/14070/l/visualizing-changes-from-eagles-backup-files?displayFullThread=true), [using it with GIT + looking through the codes to get the changes](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/01/19/hardware-version-control/) or [indicating version no. and last update date](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/93773/editing-title-block-frame-in-eagle) as a form of version control.

Is there a way to say, for each component, there is an activity log on it? (i.e. R20 changed from 100 ohms to 300 ohms etc......)

Comment: Eagle files are xml files and git works fairly well for version control out of the box. There are a few diff extensions for eagle but they all basically just screenshot various layers and overlay

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is not.

You could write a ULP script which creates a log of changes, but every change you make you would have to run the script manually. Essentially it would generate some form of list of parts, coordinates, values, etc. Then when you run the script it could compare the current values in the board with those in the log file and update them. Git could be used to version control the log file so you get a history of the changes.

Answer (score 0):

For using Eagle with git there is the alternative of using git plugins. If visual difference between two version (either PCB or SCH) is enough there is [eagle-diff](https://github.com/fxkr/eagle-diff) Although it is not easy to set up it gets the job done.

Looking at how it works it is entirely possible to write a similar plugin for git which gets the BOM of the current version and diffs it agains a bom of an older version.